# Using bottom nav bar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navbar

I am trying to make a bottom navigation bar to navigation bar between activities but I find using fragments very confusing so I tried using but its not working tried to look for something that I can use but I did not find anything online so as people who have experience can I use bottom navigation bar without fragments.

**My code:**

```
   private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
   mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


           case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(RedirectedsearchActivity.this, 
      SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
```

It didn’t work.

Comment: without fragment it will be difficult. suggest you to go with fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and make activity_main layout.. without fragment it not working that time you need each and every activity define bottom navigation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/amToolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amToolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
     />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

after that mainActivity call click event..

```
    // Set action to perform when any menu-item is selected.
    bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        item.isChecked = true
        selectFragment(item)
        false
    }
private fun selectFragment(item: MenuItem?) {
    item?.isChecked = true
    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.action_uploadFile -> {
         // here define fragment change
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the navigation component.

With it, it is much easier to work with fragments.
There are a couple of links to documentation and articles.

Documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

And tutorial https://www.androidauthority.com/android-navigation-architecture-component-908660/